# Stokes' second problem

Tags: differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to solve this equation

```
sol = u[t, x] /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    u[t, 0] == sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

however, everytime, I use `NDsolve`, it gives me the below error

> ReplaceAll::reps:
>   {NDSolve[{(u^(1,0))[t,x]==(u^(0,2))[t,x],u[0,x]==0,u[t,0]==sin[t],u[t,5]==0},u,{t,0,10},{x,0,5}]}`
>   is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and
>   so cannot be used for replacing.

Comment: sin is spelled Sin in Mathematica. Fix that and your problem goes away

Answer (score 6):

The PDE along with the initial and boundary conditions constitute the famous Stokes second problem. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Stokes-first-and-second-problems-with-COMSOL-Multiphysics) a comparison has been made among Maple, *Mathematica* and COMSOL solving the same model.

The main issue you are facing is the syntax for $sin$ which @Bill has correctly pointed out that it should be `Sin` with a capital `S` not small `s`.

Sometime back, I have tried to solve the same thing, here is my try, which is not different than yours,

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x]}
ics = {U[0, x] == 0};
bcs = {U[t, 0] == Sin[t], U[t, 10] == 0};
ibcAll = Flatten[{ics, bcs}, 1];
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ibcAll}, {U}, {t, 0, 12}, {x, 0, 10}];

DensityPlot[(U /. First@sol)[t, x], {x, 0, 4}, {t, 0, 12}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

After some struggle, I found an analytical solution to this problem.

$$
\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2L^{2}\left(
kn^{2}\pi^{2}\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)
}e^{-k\left(  \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\right)  t}-\frac{2L^{2}\left(
kn^{2}\pi^{2}\cos t+L^{2}\sin t\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi
^{4}\right)  }\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \right)  +\left(
\frac{L-x}{L}\right)  \sin\left(  t\right)
$$

Below is the derivation, and simulation for $k=1,L=5$ showing it matches the numerical solution from `NDSolve`

Solve

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}
\tag{1}\\
0  & <x<L\nonumber\\
t  & >0\nonumber
\end{align}

Initial conditions

$$
u\left(  0,x\right)  =0
$$

Boundary conditions

\begin{align*}
u\left(  0,t\right)    & =\sin\left(  t\right)  \\
u\left(  t,L\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

Let
\begin{equation}
u=v+u_{E}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $u_{E}\left(  x,t\right)  $ is steady state solution that only needs to
satisfy boundary conditions and $v\left(  x,t\right)  $ satisfies the PDE
itself but with homogenous B.C. At steady state, the PDE becomes

\begin{align*}
0  & =k\frac{d^{2}u_{E}}{dx^{2}}\\
u_{E}\left(  0\right)    & =\sin\left(  t\right)  \\
u_{E}\left(  L\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

The solution is $u_{E}\left(  t\right)  =\left(  \frac{L-x}{L}\right)
\sin\left(  t\right)  $. Hence (2) becomes

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =v\left(  x,t\right)  +\left(  \frac{L-x}{L}\right)
\sin\left(  t\right)
$$

Substituting the above in (1) gives

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\left(  \frac{L-x}{L}\right)  \cos\left(
t\right)    & =k\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}\nonumber\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}
}+\left(  \frac{x-L}{L}\right)  \cos\left(  t\right)  \nonumber\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}
}+Q\left(  x,t\right)  \tag{3}
\end{align}

With boundary conditions $u_{0}\left(  0,t\right)  =0,u\left(  L,t\right)
=0$. This is now in standard form and separation of variables can be used to
solve it.
$$
Q\left(  x,t\right)  =\left(  \frac{x-L}{L}\right)  \cos\left(  t\right)
$$
Now acts as a source term. The eigenfunctions are known to be $\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  =\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  $ where $\lambda
_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}$. Hence by eigenfunction expansion,
the solution to (3) is

\begin{equation}
v\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{3A}
\end{equation}

Substituting this into (3) gives

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{dB_{n}\left(  t\right)  }{dt}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  =k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime
}\left(  x\right)  +Q\left(  x,t\right)  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Expanding $Q\left(  x,t\right)  $ using same basis (eigenfunctions) gives

$$
Q\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$

Applying orthogonality

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{L}Q\left(  x,t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  x\right)  dx  & =\int_{0}
^{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
\Phi_{m}\left(  x\right)  dx\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \int_{0}^{L}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  x\right)  dx
\end{align*}

But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{L}\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(
x\right)  dx=\int_{0}^{L}\Phi_{m}^{2}\left(  x\right)  dx=\frac{L}{2}$ since
$\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  $ and the
above simplifies to

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{L}Q\left(  x,t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  dx  & =\frac{L}
{2}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \\
q_{n}\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}Q\left(  x,t\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  dx
\end{align*}

But $Q\left(  x,t\right)  =\left(  \frac{x-L}{L}\right)  \cos\left(  t\right)
$, hence

\begin{align*}
q_{n}\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\left(  \frac{x-L}
{L}\right)  \cos\left(  t\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  dx\\
& =\frac{-2}{n\pi}\cos\left(  t\right)
\end{align*}

Therefore $Q\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)
\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{n\pi}\cos\left(
t\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  $ and (4) becomes

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{dB_{n}\left(  t\right)  }{dt}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)    & =k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}
^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos\left(
t\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \\
\frac{dB_{n}\left(  t\right)  }{dt}\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)    &
=kB_{n}\left(  t\right)  \left(  -\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\sin\left(
\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \right)  -\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos\left(  t\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \\
\frac{dB_{n}\left(  t\right)  }{dt}+B_{n}\left(  t\right)  k\frac{n^{2}\pi
^{2}}{L^{2}}  & =-\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos\left(  t\right)
\end{align*}

This is an ODE in $B_{n}\left(  t\right)  $ whose solution is

$$
B_{n}\left(  t\right)  =C_{n}e^{-k\left(  \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\right)
t}-\frac{2L^{2}\left(  kn^{2}\pi^{2}\cos t+L^{2}\sin t\right)  }{n\pi\left(
L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)  }
$$

From (3A) $v\left(  x,t\right)  $ now becomes

\begin{equation}
v\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}e^{-k\left(  \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}
}{L^{2}}\right)  t}\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  -\frac{2L^{2}\left(
kn^{2}\pi^{2}\cos t+L^{2}\sin t\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi
^{4}\right)  }\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \tag{5}
\end{equation}

To find $C_{n}$, from initial conditions, at $t=0$ the above becomes

$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  -\frac
{2L^{2}\left(  kn^{2}\pi^{2}\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi
^{4}\right)  }\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)
$$

Hence

$$
C_{n}=\frac{2L^{2}\left(  kn^{2}\pi^{2}\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}
n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)  }
$$

Therefore (5) becomes

$$
v\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2L^{2}\left(  kn^{2}
\pi^{2}\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)  }e^{-k\left(
\frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\right)  t}-\frac{2L^{2}\left(  kn^{2}\pi^{2}\cos
t+L^{2}\sin t\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)  }\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)
$$

And since $u=v+u_{E}$ then the solution is

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2L^{2}\left(
kn^{2}\pi^{2}\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi^{4}\right)
}e^{-k\left(  \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}}{L^{2}}\right)  t}-\frac{2L^{2}\left(
kn^{2}\pi^{2}\cos t+L^{2}\sin t\right)  }{n\pi\left(  L^{4}+k^{2}n^{4}\pi
^{4}\right)  }\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  \right)  +\left(
\frac{L-x}{L}\right)  \sin\left(  t\right)
$$

To simulate

```
ClearAll[t, x, n]
k = 1; L0 = 5; max = 400; 
u[x_, t_] = 
  Sum[(((2*L0^2*(k*n^2*Pi^2))/(n*Pi*(L0^4 + k^2*n^4*Pi^4)))*
        Exp[(-k)*((n^2*Pi^2)/L0^2)*t] - 
              (2*L0^2*(k*n^2*Pi^2*Cos[t] + L0^2*Sin[t]))/(n*
          Pi*(L0^4 + k^2*Pi^4*n^4)))*Sin[((n*Pi)/L0)*x], 
         {n, 1, max}] + ((L0 - x)/L0)*Sin[t]; 

Manipulate[Grid[{{"Analytical solution"},
{Plot[Evaluate[u[x,t]],{x,0,5},PlotRange->{{0,5},{-1.1,1.1}},
      ImageSize->400]}}],
{{t,0,"t"},0,100,.01}
]
```

[image]

Here is the numerical solution from `NDSolve` using zhk code posted above to compare with

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
pdeset = {Derivative[1, 0][U][t, x] == Derivative[0, 2][U][t, x]}
ics = {U[0, x] == 0};
bcs = {U[t, 0] == Sin[t], U[t, 5] == 0};
ibcAll = {ics, bcs};
numericalSol = NDSolve[{pdeset, ibcAll}, U, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 5}];
Manipulate[Grid[{{"Numerical solution"},
   {Plot[Evaluate[U[t, x] /. numericalSol], {x, 0, 5}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 400]}}],
 {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 100, .01}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: A wonderful exercise, but my choice is to first let Mathematica work. With Mathematica 11.1.1 one can choose between the numerical and analytical solution.